# Check whether the polynomial is irreducible or not

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Is polynomial $f(X)=X^{p^n}-X$ is irreducible and separable in $\mathbb{F_p[X]}$?

I know that derivative of f(X) is $p^{n}X^{p^n-1}-1$ which is 0-1=-1 so it has no multiple root and hence separable; since it is field with $\mathrm{char}=p$ so only question is about irreducibilty?

Comment: Maybe it’s a notation error- but check the derivative again. Not the it totally matters here.

Comment: Surely $f(X)=X(X^{p^n-1}-1)$?

Comment: So can we say it is reducible ? For that I guess we need to show both of them are non-unit

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown please give  some more information.

Comment: @Ninjahatori  LordSharkTheUnknown  has already factorized the polynomial you gave. Does not that answer your question? Why do you want more information?